# How to access Vertical Tabs from Contrib Modules in Panels?

Tags: panels, forms

Drupal node forms have a vertical tabs area, which provides options such as "Revision Information", "Authoring Information", "Publishing Options" etc.
Contrib modules such as [Node Hierarchy](https://drupal.org/project/nodehierarchy) and [XML sitemap](https://drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) can add custom tabs to this area.

How do you access these tabs from contrib modules in Panels.

In the past, with Drupal 7 & Panels, you could access them via the "Form" section of "Panels > Add Content".
However, I am creating a new Drupal 7 site and I can no longer access Vertical Tabs from Contrib modules. Only the tabs from Code Drupal modules are shown.

Steps I have tried to overcome the problem:

1) I have made a fresh install with just Panels and Node Hierarchy.
I have made a second fresh install with just Panels and Xml Sitemap.
In both cases, Vertical Tabs from Contrib modules are not accessible.

2) I have tried installing [Node Vertical Tab Elements](https://drupal.org/project/node_vertical_tab_elements). It too only gives access to core tabs (and not tabs added by Contrib modules).

3) I have tried upgrading my older Drupal 7 sites to the latest versions of Drupal 7. In these older sites, the Vertical Tabs from Contrib modules are still accessible, so I am not sure if this means a special setting is required to access the tabs. I have disabled all custom themes and modules on the site, so I know the tabs are not coming from custom code.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out. It is Ctools 7.13 that breaks it (Ctools 7.12 works fine). 
I have raised an issue here:
https://drupal.org/node/2147191

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this should work.

In your 1) scenario, where you restricted your installation to the minimum amount of modules -- you might have run into a change/bug with a module version which you intentionaly have upgraded. Try not to test with "most recent versions".

Because you phrased your experience as "in the past you could ...".